# can anyone find out why only the x axis is working?

Tags: python

i was trying give my own take at makeing some sort of "wave function colapse", it seems to work on the x axis but i dont know whats the problem with the y one.

```
def colapseMap(map):

    for y in range(len(map)):
        for x in range(len(map)):

            up = map[(y-1)%len(map)][x%len(map)]
            upPosibilities = []
            for i in range(len(up)): upPosibilities += posibleNextState(up[i], initialEntropy)

            down = map[(y+1)%len(map)][x%len(map)]
            downPosibilities = []
            for i in range(len(down)): downPosibilities += posibleNextState(down[i], initialEntropy)

            left = map[y%len(map)][(x-1)%len(map)]
            leftPosibilities = []
            for i in range(len(left)): leftPosibilities += posibleNextState(left[i], initialEntropy)

            right = map[y%len(map)][(x+1)%len(map)]
            rightPosibilities = []
            for i in range(len(right)): rightPosibilities += posibleNextState(right[i], initialEntropy)

            accpns = list(set(list(set(list(set(upPosibilities).intersection(downPosibilities))).intersection(leftPosibilities))).intersection(rightPosibilities)) #adjacent cells comun posible next states
            map[y][x] = [accpns[randrange(len(accpns))]]

    return map
```

it was suposed to output something kid of like this:

```
[0] [1] [1] [1] [1] [2] [3] [2] [2] [1]
[1] [2] [1] [1] [0] [1] [2] [2] [3] [2]
[1] [2] [2] [1] [1] [1] [2] [3] [3] [2]
[2] [3] [3] [2] [2] [2] [3] [3] [4] [3]
[3] [3] [4] [3] [3] [2] [3] [4] [4] [4]
[4] [4] [5] [4] [4] [3] [3] [4] [5] [4]
[3] [4] [5] [5] [5] [4] [4] [4] [4] [3]
[2] [3] [4] [4] [4] [4] [4] [3] [3] [2]
[2] [3] [3] [3] [3] [2] [3] [2] [2] [1]
[1] [2] [3] [2] [1] [2] [3] [2] [1] [0]
```

but it does this instead:

```
[0] [1] [1] [0] [1] [2] [3] [2] [2] [1]
[0] [1] [1] [0] [1] [2] [3] [2] [2] [1]
[0] [1] [1] [0] [1] [2] [3] [2] [2] [1]
[0] [1] [1] [0] [1] [2] [3] [2] [2] [1]
[0] [1] [1] [0] [1] [2] [3] [2] [2] [1]
[0] [1] [1] [0] [1] [2] [3] [2] [2] [1]
[0] [1] [1] [0] [1] [2] [3] [2] [2] [1]
[0] [1] [1] [0] [1] [2] [3] [2] [2] [1]
[0] [1] [1] [0] [1] [2] [3] [2] [2] [1]
[0] [1] [1] [0] [1] [2] [3] [2] [2] [1]
```

Comment: FYI calling a variable `map` is not recommended, because that's the name of a built-in Python function. And you should get into the habit of using `snake_case` in Python rather than `camelCase` - e.g. `initialEntropy` should be `initial_entropy`, etc. Also, this code is not self-explanatory; it's not apparent how it should work, so it's not apparent what's not working.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") This is not a code-writing, code-debugging, or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Thus, can anyone find out why only the x axis is working? isn't a valid question.  You should try debugging your code.  See [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Six Debugging Techniques for Python Programmers](https://medium.com/techtofreedom/six-debugging-techniques-for-python-programmers-cb25a4baaf4b.

Comment: You're loop boundaries look wrong. You're traversing through the entire array for both `x` and `y` instead of through rows and columns.

Comment: That looks like a problem in the initialization of `map`, which you didn't show - perhaps something like `[[0]*n]*n` that doesn't actually make all of the rows distinct objects.